# asp.net mvc authentication only works when debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an asp.net mvc application that works fine under visual studio but when I publish it to the localhost, I'm unable to login.

I already striped down the code and found that `MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)` won't work but the next line `FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)` works fine.

On the web config I got the following:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add autogenerateschema="true"
             connectionStringName="ConnString"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
             applicationName="/"
             name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </providers>
 </membership>
 <profile defaultProvider="MySqlProfileProvider">
   <providers>
     <clear/>
     <add name="MySqlProfileProvider"
             type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
             connectionStringName="ConnString" applicationName="/" autogenerateschema="true"/>
    </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="MySqlRoleProvider" autogenerateschema="true" connectionStringName="ConnString" applicationName="/"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      </providers>
   </roleManager>
```

The ConnString is ok because other parts of the application work just fine (including the FormsService.SignIn).

Where's the physical path where Visual Studio debug applications so I can compare Web.configs with the one on my localhost IIS?

Comment: Are you using IIS when you are running with Visual Studio or are you using the built-in ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: build-in ASP.NET Development Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to found the problem, it was kinda embarrassing actually.

I was building the project with framework 4.0 but was deploying it to a Application pool using .net framework 2.0.

Though I still find strange that the ValidateUser method depends on the framework

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had a similar issue, this answer made me look into my application pool. Although it was on v4.0, my application was not working. It was able to read the values from the db but not add/write any new roles to the db. Then I changed the Identity on the ApplicationPool from default to NetworkService. That works now !

Answer (score 0):

You may need to **add the domain to your web.config** when you publish.

```
<system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10080" path="/" protection="All" domain="yourdomain.com" />
    </authentication>

</system.web>
```

NOTE: When debugging in visual studio, DO NOT include the domain. You can use the web.config transformation feature to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

For you guys that might have this problem, my issue was my path in authentication.forms section of web.config.  My application was running under the directory `wwwroot/myappdir`, my path logically set to `/myappdir`

```
<authentication mode = "forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" path="/myappdir" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="Validation">
</authentication>
```

When I'd run the debugger, it would work flawlessly starting the app with `http://localhost:xxxx/myappdir/`.

However, this was the only website running on my server so, for convenience, I'd test in my variety of browsers from the website root, `http://localhost/`, and kept bouncing right back to the login form.

It was a couple of hours before it dawned on me what was happening.