# User not recognized as logged in when application is run as Start Without Debugging, user authentication works perfectly when run as Start Debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio, authentication, asp.net-identity

I've built a small ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2019, starting from the ASP.NET MVC web application project template for VB, which uses the default Individual User Accounts for authentication. I'm nearing the end of development, and somewhere along the way I lost the ability to log in to my application when I run it without the debugger attached via CTRL-F5: Start Without Debugging. Running the application with the debugger attached via F5: Start Debugging and any other run method that attaches the debugger allows the application to behave as expected.

On startup, the web application asks the user to log in. After a successful login, the expected behavior is a redirect to the home page, but currently a successful login only shows the login page again, and I believe the application doesn't recognize the user as authenticated.

I started debugging with the old clean, recompile, and rebuild and didn't have any luck there. Added a throw statement inside the login method's success statement and verified that the login attempt does succeed. The login method with this throw statement (located in `AccountController.vb`) is shown below. The sign in attempt does trigger the `SignIn.Success` case.

```
' POST: /Account/Login
<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Async Function Login(model As LoginViewModel, returnUrl As String) As Task(Of ActionResult)
    If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
        Return View(model)
    End If

    ' This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    ' To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
    Dim result = Await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout := False)
    Select Case result
        Case SignInStatus.Success
            Throw New System.Exception("Sign In Succeeded") 'Throws both with and without the debugger attached
            Return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)
        Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
            Return View("Lockout")
        Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
            Return RedirectToAction("SendCode", New With {
                returnUrl,
                model.RememberMe
            })
        Case Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.")
            Return View(model)
    End Select
End Function
```

Strangely, the inability to log in persists even if I remove the only two `<Authorize>` attributes in the project, which I thought would do away with the log in screen all together. (They're attached to the `AccountController` and `ManagerController` classes, and their placement matches other projects I've completed in the past using the same project templates)

One of the only related internet resources I could find is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300625/asp-net-mvc-authentication-only-works-when-debugging). I'm both building and deploying to targetFramework 4.7.2, and my web.config file was generated by the project template except for the database connection string, but I've included it just in case someone spots something awry.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=my secret token" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=very secret connection string"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlRoleProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
        applicationName="RFIDDataEntry"
        connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      ....
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

**TLDR:** My VB.NET web application doesn't recognize a user as logged in when the application is run without the debugger attached, even though the login attempt succeeds.

Comment: Update: the mysterious non-debugger-attached log-in problem disappeared after I left the code alone for a few days. The only git-tracked change between broken and functional versions was the creation of an obj/ folder, with subfolders Debug/ and Release/. Why it broke is still a mystery, but I'm happy the program works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same issue last few days. My browser is Edge Developer. After removing .vs folder the problem persist. Then I remove all cache from browser and Voila, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting the **.vs** folder.